# How can I share memory between numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, memory

I have a large numpy array of size 100x100. Among these 10000 values, there are only about 50 unique values. So I want to create a second array of length 50, containing these unique values, and then somehow map the large array to the smaller array. Effectively, I want to store just 50 values in my system instead of redundant 10000 values.

Slices of arrays seem to share memory, but as soon as I use specific indexing, memory sharing is lost.

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
b = a[:3]
indices = [0,1,2]
c = a[indices]
print(b,c)
print(np.shares_memory(a,b),np.shares_memory(a,c))
```

This gives the output:

```
[1 2 3] [1 2 3]
True False
```

Even though b and c are referring to the same values of a, b(the slice) shares memory with a while c doesn't. If I execute b[0] = 100, a[0] also becomes 100 since they share memory. That is not the case with c.

I want to make c, which is a collection of values which are all from a, share memory with a.

Comment: I don’t fully understand what your output should look like but does numpy.unique() help you?

Comment: You need to read more about the basics of how arrays are defined and stored, and with that the distinction between `view` and `copy`.  The `view` can share memory because it just differs in `shape`, `strides` (and a memory pointer).  But sharing memory in the `indices` case requires storing that `indices` list along with `c`; in effect doing the indexing operation fresh each time you access `c`.

Comment: What's the dtype of the array, i.e. what is the type of the elements you're storing?

Comment: @JohnZwinck The dtype is numpy.int64.

Comment: @hpaulj So it is not possible in the indices case?

Answer (score 0):

In general it is not possible to save memory in this way.  The reason is that your data consists of 64-bit integers, and pointers are also 64-bit integers, so if you try to store each value exactly once in some auxiliary array and then point at those values, you will end up using basically the same amount of space.

The answer would be different if for example some of your arrays are subsets of other ones, or you if you were storing large types like long strings.

Answer (score 0):

So make a random array with a small set of unique values:

```
In [45]: x = np.random.randint(0,10,(10,10))                                                                 
In [46]: x                                                                                                   
Out[46]: 
array([[4, 3, 8, 5, 4, 8, 8, 1, 8, 1],
       [9, 2, 7, 2, 9, 5, 3, 9, 3, 3],
       [6, 2, 6, 9, 4, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7],
       [1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 9, 4, 2, 6, 2],
       [8, 1, 6, 8, 3, 9, 5, 0, 8, 5],
       [4, 9, 1, 4, 1, 2, 8, 4, 7, 2],
       [4, 5, 2, 4, 8, 0, 1, 4, 4, 7],
       [2, 2, 0, 5, 3, 0, 3, 3, 3, 9],
       [3, 1, 0, 6, 4, 8, 8, 3, 5, 2],
       [7, 5, 9, 2, 8, 0, 8, 1, 7, 8]])
```

Find the unique ones:

```
In [48]: np.unique(x)                                                                                        
Out[48]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

better yet the unique values plus an array that lets us map those values on the original:

```
In [49]: np.unique(x, return_inverse=True)                                                                   
Out[49]: 
(array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),
 array([4, 3, 8, 5, 4, 8, 8, 1, 8, 1, 9, 2, 7, 2, 9, 5, 3, 9, 3, 3, 6, 2,
        6, 9, 4, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 9, 4, 2, 6, 2, 8, 1, 6, 8,
        3, 9, 5, 0, 8, 5, 4, 9, 1, 4, 1, 2, 8, 4, 7, 2, 4, 5, 2, 4, 8, 0,
        1, 4, 4, 7, 2, 2, 0, 5, 3, 0, 3, 3, 3, 9, 3, 1, 0, 6, 4, 8, 8, 3,
        5, 2, 7, 5, 9, 2, 8, 0, 8, 1, 7, 8]))
```

There's a value in the reverse mapping for each element in the original.